# org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: cause: cxf bundle

Tags: apache, web-services, wso2, cxf

`org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied`.

This exception is getting due to the cxf bundle. I am not sure how to get away from this. Anyone has any idea about this issue?

The service client works as a java program but when deployed as a service in WSO2 application server it throws this exception. The cause in CXF bundle but not sure how to avoid it.

Exception trace:

```
WARN {org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain} -  Application {http://test.tss.com/}Sync#{http://test.tss.com/}hello has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at
```

I don't have any policy XML. The wsdl includes the policy tags:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN_BN_binding_SOAP12">
  <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/" uri="http://xml.sap.com/2006/11/esi/esp/binxml" wsp:Optional="true" />
  <saptrnbnd:OptimizedMimeSerialization xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" wsp:Optional="true" />
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
     <wsp:All>
        <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/security/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
           <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:TransportToken>
                 <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:HttpsToken>
                       <wsp:Policy>
                          <sp:HttpBasicAuthentication />
                       </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:HttpsToken>
                 </wsp:Policy>
              </sp:TransportToken>
              <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                 <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:Basic128Rsa15 />
                 </wsp:Policy>
              </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <sp:Layout>
                 <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:Strict />
                 </wsp:Policy>
              </sp:Layout>
           </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportBinding>
     </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
     <wsp:All>
        <wsrmp:RMAssertion xmlns:wsrmp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrmp/200702">
           <wsp:Policy />
        </wsrmp:RMAssertion>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" />
     </wsp:All>
     <wsp:All>
        <wsrm:RMAssertion xmlns:wsrm="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/policy" />
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing xmlns:wsaw="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" />
     </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
```

Comment: Hi, You can post the policy xml that you use to see its structure

Comment: Hi, I dont have any policy xml. the wsdl includes the policy tags.I added the policy details at the end of the exception in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. 
I have added the tag  to the cxf file and set the right security certificates
Sample cxf file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xmlns:httpj="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration"
    xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xmlns:p="http://cxf.apache.org/policy"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd          
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws                                     
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd         
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd         
http://cxf.apache.org/policy http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/policy.xsd         
http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration             
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd         
http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration       
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd         
http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security                    
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd  ">

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <p:policies />
            <cxf:logging />
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
    <jaxws:server id="CustomerSyncService" address="/customer_sync_service">
        <jaxws:serviceBean>
            <bean class="com.CustomerService" />
        </jaxws:serviceBean>
    </jaxws:server>

</beans>
```